# android phonegap application exit on back button press

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am doing an applicationn in android phonegap.In the application I want to show a website in iframe.I have done it and it works fine.But when i click back button from the iframe page,it exit the application,not going to back page.When I click back button from the iframe page it shows the following warning and exit application

1.No keyboard for id 0
2.Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
3.KeyDown has been triggered on the view
4.onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/index.html#)

Can anyone help me please.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you override backbutton behavior:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", yourCallbackFunction, false);
```